# JSON implementation in iOS 6

Tags: ios, database, json

I wanted to ask you if we can use the NSJSONSerialization that comes with iOS to do all our JSON-related work.

Is it a proper replacement for other libraries like SBJson, JSONKit, NextiveJSON, or TouchJSON?  Are they equivalent regarding functionality?

I have many JSON objects that feed my charts locally but now I'm going to start querying a remote DB to retrieve the information and build those objects.

How do you make the decision to go with one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a replacement for all of those.  You make a decision based on how you feel.  I use NSJSONSerialization because it is there and easy to use...no need to worry about downloading other stuff.  What "functionality" do you need?  A JSON parser only needs to do 2 things:  Encode JSON from objects and decode JSON to objects.

Comment: Hi borrrden, I'm new with JSON so I'm just figuring out the first thing. Now that I know that I'll continue with the next step. I'm building a reporting app that will query a DB and feed the charting library using JSON objects. Thanks!

Comment: JSONKit is still a bit faster (25-40%, according to the developer), but I'd recommend going with `NSJSONSerialization`, too, as this is certainly the most future proof way.